# Mediawiki export - metadata only?

Tags: mediawiki-api

In MediaWiki, you can download a page's history at:

```
index.php/Special:Export?pages=page1&history
```

Is there any way to exclude the page-contents from this, and just get the list of revisions, authors, and dates?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you can't do that using `Special:Export`.

But the API is much more flexible, for example, you can do something like:

```
api.php?action=query&titles=page1&prop=revisions&rvlimit=max
```

and it should return what you want. If you want to specify what exactly should it return, use `rvprop`.